# For Brownian motion $B_t,$ we have $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{B_t}{t^{\alpha}}=0$ almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

This might be a silly problem. I am trying to show that $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{B_t}{t^{\alpha}}=0$ almost surely if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}.$ I can apply Chebyshev's inequality to show that $P(|B_{t}/t^{\alpha}|>\epsilon)\to 0$ as $t\to \infty.$ This tells me that $\frac{B_t}{t^{\alpha}}$ converges to $0$ in probability. But I am not sure how to argue the almost sure limit. I found at the very beginning of a book I am reading, so I am looking forward to something which does not use $0-1$ laws if that's possible. I am wondering if this can be done cheaply using the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is easy at all from the ground up, but it can be derived from some other well known facts, which are perhaps proved in your text.

Let $W_t=tB_{1/t}$. It is well known that $W_t$ is also a Brownian motion. Then $$\lim_{t\to \infty}B_{t}/t^{\alpha}=\lim_{t\to\infty}W_{1/t}/t^{\alpha-1}=\lim_{s\to0}W_s/s^{1-\alpha}$$
The fact that the last limit is zero is the definition of $W_s$ being Hölder continuous at $0$ with exponent $1-\alpha$. The fact that $W_s$ is Hölder continuous for all exponents less than $\frac12$ is often proved early on in textbooks.

Comment: That is right. But proving that Brownian motion is Hölder with exponent $\le 1/2$ is, in my opinion, non-trivial. I was going through Stochastic Processes By R. F. Bass. In this book he merely introduces Brownian motion (even the existence is not shown) in the second chapter. In Chapter 3 he proves basic properties of martingale and this problem appears in the exercise in Chapter 3. So, I was wondering if it follows from basic tools that one learns in first course in Probability.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho So why don't you use the hint? The idea is similar to the proof of Theorem 7.2

Comment: Yeah Right! I could finally do it using the hint. (It was silly of me to not read the hint, it was on the next page and I didn’t turn to the next page.) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta=(\alpha-1/2)/2$. By the [law of iterated logarithm](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Introduction_to_Stochastic_Calculus_with.html?id=JYzW0uqQxB0C&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Theorem%203.31&f=false),
$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{|B_t|}{t^\alpha}\le  \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{|B_t|}{t^{
\beta}\sqrt{t\ln\ln t}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t^{\beta}}\times\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{|B_t|}{\sqrt{t\ln\ln t}}=0\quad\text{a.s.}
$$